# How to create a handler that will return the 'ID' of the list element 'LI' Clicked

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a handler that will return the 'ID'  of the list element Clicked.   I have tried many variations (with and without the For loop), but I can't seem to make it work. Your help is appreciated.

## Script

```
function getItems () {
    var cList = document.getElementById("cMenu");
    var cItems = cList.getElementsByTagName("LI");

    for (var i = 0; i < cItems.length; i++) {

        cItems[i].onclick = function(){
            var theId = this.id;
        };
    }
    console.log(theId);
}
```

## HTML Source

```
<ul id="cMenu">
  <li>
    Parent item 1
    <ul>
      <li id="item1">Child item 1</li>
      <li id="item2">Child item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Parent item 2
    <ul>
      <li id="item3">Child item 3</li>
      <li id="item4">Child item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well, the `console.log(theId);` will happen before the click. Move it inside the event handler. You cannot really *return* anything from an event handler, since you don't know when it is going to be executed.

Comment: are you trying to get the id of the clicked li item or the list of the li items inside the submenus ul?

Answer (score 0):

Move `console.log(theId)` into your `onclick` function and make sure you call `getItems()` so it is run once to set everything up.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xs32u/)

```
function getItems () {
    var cList = document.getElementById("cMenu");
    var cItems = cList.getElementsByTagName("LI");

    for (var i = 0; i < cItems.length; i++) {

        cItems[i].onclick = function(){
            var theId = this.id;
            console.log(theId);
        };
    }
}
getItems();
```

Comment: Thank You.  My issue must be at a higher level, as it is not working.  I will rework the basic structure of my script.  BTW: getItems gets called with window.onload

Comment: The only way I see it failing is if you have multiple elements with the id `cMenu` or you didn't put `getItems()` in to call it.

Comment: Maybe it's the way I'm testing (firebug inside Dreamweaver).  Any I will try to test in a different structure.  Thank for all the Help.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/5XSUG/

```
var listItems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++)
{
    listItems[i].onclick = function(e)
    {
        e.stopPropagation();
        window.alert(e.target.id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to only get the `id` of the `cList > li > ul > li` then you can add a certain `className` to all those list items to avoid adding event handler to parent `li` items `cList > li` e.g.:

```
<ul id="cMenu">
    <li>Parent item 1
        <ul>
            <li class="item" id="item1">Child item 1</li>
            <li class="item" id="item2">Child item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Parent item 2
        <ul>
            <li class="item" id="item3">Child item 3</li>
            <li class="item" id="item4">Child item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

then you can use this code to get the `id` of the clicked `li` item:

```
var cList = document.getElementById("cMenu"),
    cItem = cList.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (var i in cItem) {
    if (cItem[i].className == "item") {
        cItem[i].onclick = function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            var elm = event.currentTarget || event.srcElement;
            console.log(elm.id);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you don't have to wrap the code with `function` so that it will run when document loads, you just need to add it to the body section just before `</body>` tag

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/4ZQ3e/)