# Need function to wait until event handler has finished before executing next function

Tags: javascript, sqlite, air

I have seen many similar questions, but none have actually answered my issue.  I would think it would be simple, but I guess it is not.

I need to call a function 20 times, each with a different set of SQL statements.
The function called performs a SQL query and the result is handled by an eventHandler.  I need the check for the event handler to finish before executing the next function call.

As the event handler is asynchronous, the calling function completes without waiting for the handler.  I need the queryFunction wait for queryHandler to complete before going to the next queryFunction.  While my project is AIR, I suspect it's not part of the issue.

I hope I have been clear, I am relatively new to javascript.

```
function mainFunction(){
   queryFunction (var1, var2);  // There would be twenty of these with 
   queryFunction (var1, var2);  //  different values for var1 and var2
   queryFunction (var1, var2);
   queryFunction (var1, var2);
   // etc, etc....
}

function queryFunction (){
    var sqlStatment =   'SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3'+
        'FROM [TableName]  ' +
        'WHERE Field1= var1 AND Field2= var2'; //simplified code            
var stmt = new air.SQLStatement();
stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
stmt.text = sqlStatment;
stmt.addEventListener(air.SQLEvent.RESULT, queryHandler);
stmt.addEventListener(air.SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);   
stmt.execute();
}

    function queryHandler(event){ 
        // queryHandler code
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This gets tricky. You really want some sort of a queue (of function calls, or of query parameters). Your query handler (or result handler if needed) would kick off the next query in the queue when it was finished.

```
var queue = [];

function mainFunction(){
   queryFunction (var1, var2);  // There would be twenty of these with 
   queryFunction (var1, var2);  //  different values for var1 and var2
   queryFunction (var1, var2);
   queryFunction (var1, var2);
   go();
}

function queryFunction (){
   queue.push( arguments );
}

function go() {
   nextQuery();
}

function nextQuery() {
   if (queue.length > 0)
   {
     params = queue.shift();

     var sqlStatment =   'SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3'+
        'FROM [TableName]  ' +
        'WHERE Field1= ' + params[0] + ' AND Field2= ' + params[1]; //simplified code            
     var stmt = new air.SQLStatement();
     stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
     stmt.text = sqlStatment;
     stmt.addEventListener(air.SQLEvent.RESULT, queryHandler);
     stmt.addEventListener(air.SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);   
     stmt.execute();
   }
}

function queryHandler(event){ 
    // queryHandler code
    // ...
    // and then...
    nextQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I think I understand the solution.  Is arguments literal in queue.push?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's an array of parameters passed to a function.

Comment: Thanks, it will take a while to implement, as there was other code in the mainFuction that I will have to move.  I will let you know how it works....

Comment: It appears to have worked.  I have another problem with the sql query that is confusing the results.  However, it does look like it is performing the queries one at a time.  Thanks again for the Help!

Comment: I just wanted to confirm the solution.  I fixed my query issue.  The functions now run in order, one at a time.  Thanks !!!

Comment: You're welcome. You may want to Accept the answer, and do the same at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706555/how-to-create-a-handler-that-will-return-the-id-of-the-list-element-li-click